# insert initial data to sql lite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing an expense tracker where I want to populate the DB with a few records when the application first start. I tried to call the method in my splash activity and add the data.! But when I clear my application data and start the application for the first time an error occurs saying that there is no such column.

The log cat error is as shown below.

```
06-30 18:09:58.834: E/SQLiteLog(18380): (1) no such column: exp_type
06-30 18:10:00.826: D/AndroidRuntime(18380): Shutting down VM
06-30 18:10:00.826: W/dalvikvm(18380): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416b8318)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sliit.expenseanalyzer/com.sliit.expenseanalyzer.SplashActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: exp_type (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM expense_type Order BY exp_type DESC
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: exp_type (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM expense_type Order BY exp_type DESC
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at com.sliit.expenseanalyzer.util.DatabaseHandler.getAllExpenseTypes(DatabaseHandler.java:218)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at com.sliit.expenseanalyzer.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:29)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
06-30 18:10:00.856: E/AndroidRuntime(18380):    ... 11 more
```

How can I populate the data when the application starts for the first time! It's only few records so I'm not worried about performance.

It would be a great help!

Thank you.

**DATABASE CODE**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Create user table
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_PW + " TEXT," + KEY_SESSION
                + " INTEGER" + ")";

        String CREATE_EXPENSE_TYPE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE
                + " (" + KEY_EXPENSE_ID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT" + KEY_EXPENSE_TYPE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EXPENSE_TYPE_TABLE);
    }
```

Method I use to add records

```
public Long addExpenseType(String expense) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_EXPENSE_TYPE, expense);

        Long row = db.insert(TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE, null, values);
        db.close();

        return row;
    }
```

String Values:

```
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "expenseManager";

    // Database Tables
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
    private static final String TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE = "expense_type";

    // User table columns
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "full_name";
    private static final String KEY_PW = "password";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_SESSION = "session";

    // Expense type table columns
    private static final String KEY_EXPENSE_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_EXPENSE_TYPE = "exp_type";
```

Comment: Please include relevant code.

Comment: check your table creation code. seems you are trying to access wrong column

Comment: i think he is asking for table creation code

Comment: While you are using constants, it does not tell us the real string values therein.  You must supply that code.

Comment: Missed a `,` after `AUTOINCREMENT` at ` " (" + KEY_EXPENSE_ID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT" + KEY_EXPENSE_TYPE + " `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a habit of formatting your code well. The last column definition does not have a comma :

```
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER 
            + "(" 
            + KEY_ID      + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
            + KEY_NAME    + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_EMAIL   + " TEXT, " 
            + KEY_PW      + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_SESSION + " INTEGER "
            + ")";

    String CREATE_EXPENSE_TYPE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE
            + "(" 
            + KEY_EXPENSE_ID   + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_EXPENSE_TYPE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY "
            + ")";
```

Comment: it's the comma that was missing!

Answer (score 2):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: exp_type
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM expense_type Order BY
>   exp_type DESC

This is your error:

```
String CREATE_EXPENSE_TYPE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXPENSE_TYPE
                + " (" + KEY_EXPENSE_ID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT" +  
   KEY_EXPENSE_TYPE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY" + ")
```

You need a space after `INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT`

```
KEY_EXPENSE_ID + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT" +  
       KEY_EXPENSE_TYPE
```

evaluates to:

"id integer autoincrementexp_type"

Comment: it should have since I create the table in the database handler class!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri I don't see any code in your create statement that reference the value exp_type.  All you have shown is references to constant strings, not the values of those strings.

Comment: I've added the strings! sorry for not adding them on the first place!

Answer (score 2):

try to add a flag in your `user preferences`/`shared preferences` to check the apps first run and then upon return you can decide if you want to create your db or read it !

 have a look here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

 **EDIT**

 or just check if dbexists instead of user pref flag

Answer (score 1):

```
private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "TheftData";
    private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "UserDetails";
    String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
            " (Username VARCHAR, Password VARCHAR," +                   
            " );";
```

Then in onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
try {
        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL(CreateTable);
        sampleDB.close();
        }

    catch(Exception e)
    {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    sampleDB.close();
    }
```

and to add data

```
 public void insertData(String username,String password)
    {

        sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        sampleDB.execSQL(CreateTable);
        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " Values ('"+username+"','"+ password+"');");
        sampleDB.close();

    }
```